# Addittional parameters using macro from Excell to pull data from Access

Tags: excel, vba

I have a query in access database.
And I need to record macro to pull data with this query from Access.
But, when I pull that query with macro and Excel automaticly create a Sub with macro code. Problem is in that I need edit data in where clause of query in that macros Sub to add parameter from Excel (user input this data on one sheet). How can I write this ?
Help me please, because I dont have an idea anymore.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? Any code you have (weather it works or not), your query etc.

Comment: I will explain more tomorow, because code and query is on my notebook on work, I will appreciate any help because I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, the relevant code and the specific issues you are having. You may find http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help useful. Edit the question to add details. Consider deleting this question. As it stands now it can only gather downvotes which impacts your ability to ask questions. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151511

It'll let you run a query in access and modify the parameters.  I don't have a working version of access and excel to test it out for ya.  Good luck.